# Identify the highest normal form of the relational table

Tags: sql, forms, normalization, transitive-dependency

This is a assignment from school. Here is the question.

BranchCustomer(branch, customer, employee)

The attributes of the relational table BranchCustomer satisfy the following sets of functional dependencies:

•   branch, customer >>  employee
•   employee >> branch

I would think that the highest NF would be 2NF as there is a transitive dependency (empployee >> branch). but i was told otherwise as branch is 1 of the composite key and thus it is a 3NF. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If branch is in a candidate key, it does not violate 3NF, the requirement of an attribute being non-transitively dependant is only for non-prime attributes. So yes, this is correct.